# My state is not changing to call1 from call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components, setstate

I want to make a `DynamicBarChart`, but I am unable to update the state. Could you figure out why?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { DynamicBarChart } from 'react-dynamic-charts';
import 'react-dynamic-charts/dist/index.css';

class Dynamicchart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      data: [{ "name": "Call", "values": [] }]
    }
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const mockData = [
      {
        id: 1,
        value: 10,
        label: "hey",
        color: "red"
      }
    ]
    const newwData = [{
      "name": "Call1",
      "values": mockData // Here i changed the values of the data
    }]

    this.setState({
      data: newwData // This method is unable to change the state.data component
    });

    // This still gives the value of data which is given in constructor 
    // Why has the value not changed?
    console.log(this.state.data) 
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <DynamicBarChart
        data={this.state.data}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Dynamicchart
```

This code is showing "Call" in front-end, I want the value of "Call1". This means that the state did not change. Can you explain why this is happening?

Comment: `setState` is async, it will not be updated immediately after calling the updater. Log inside of the `render` instead and you will see the updated values.

Comment: Also, attempting to change the state of an object in `componentDidMount` from what was set in the `constructor` could be contributing to the problem. Why set it in both places?

Comment: [Docs on `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) that explains the behavior of `setState`. [In depth answer](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11527#issuecomment-360199710).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: render() {
    console.log(this.state.data)
    
    return (

      <DynamicBarChart
      
        data={this.state.data}

      />
      
    );
  }

}  //yes i did this but still the value showing in front end is call instead of call1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a random `key` to the `DynamicBarChart` component will solve the issue:

```js
    return <DynamicBarChart key={Math.random()} data={this.state.data} />;
```

I created a sandbox to demonstrate this with a fake delay in this [Example with Simulated API Request](https://codesandbox.io/embed/stupefied-snow-s5ks2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

---

That being said, the comment of [@Waheed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7713920/waheed-akhtar) is valid, regarding accessing `this.state.data` right after calling `this.setState({...})` as the latter is async. If you want to see the data update, use the `console.log` in the `render()` block or as a callback of the `setState` like @Waheed mentioned in his reply.

The reason why the component is not re-rendering is because you're mutating the state with new data. By setting a random key you're forcing the `DynamicBarChart` component re-rendering.

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is an `Async` operation so you have to use `callback` for doing anything after `setState`, use `console.log()` in this way in the callback or put `console.log` in the render function.

```js
    const newwData = [{
      "name": "Call1",
      "values": mockData
    }]

    this.setState({
      data: newwData
    }, () => console.log(this.state.data));
```

Comment: Then please make a snack on expo with reproducible demo and share it with me.